# Convergence or divergence of integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{x \sin x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm struggling with how to show that

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{x \sin x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}dx
$$
either diverges or converges.

If we call the integrand $f(x)$ then 
$$
f(x)\leq g(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}\forall x\in[1, \infty)
$$
so I tried to show that $g(x)$ converges (and hence that $f(x)$ must converge), but with no luck. Another idea I had was to show that

$$
h(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}
$$
diverges, which would mean that $f(x)$ diverges too since

$$
h(x)\leq f(x)\forall x\in[1, \infty)
$$
but I got nowhere.

I also tried to use some partial integration and get two expressions rather than one, but that didn't help.

Can I get some hints? **Please note that it's homework so no solutions, thanks**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your integrand is not positive, so you have to use absolute values. For the estimate, you have to get rid of the $1$.

Comment: Why is it positive? $\sin x$ is between -1 and 1, and everything else is positive.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "not positive".

Comment: I see, that makes more sense. I think I got it now. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. The suggestion was an attempt to lead you to the strategy now shown in the other answer.

Comment: I appreciate that. One question: if I show that the absolute value of the function converges, does that imply that it's convergent (in the 'non-absolute' sense)? Absolute convergence is discussed in later chapters for some reason, so it's a bit of a new concept...

Comment: Yes, because convergence means that $|\int_m^nf|$ is small for big enough $n,m$. And $|\int_m^nf|\leq\int_m^n|f|$.

Answer (score 1):

It is (absolutely) convergent by the comparison test since $\int_1^\infty|\frac{x\sin x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}|dx\leq \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx$ (convergent by $p$ test since $p=3/2>1$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am able to develop some reasoning now why it should converge.